# UITableView and segmented controller moving under navigation bar in IOS 11

Tags: ios, swift3, ios11

The `UITableView` top and segmented controller is hiding under the navigation bar which is happening only in iOS 11.
My controllers' flow is

> ```
> Navi Controller ->
>   TabBar Controller ->
>       ViewControllers
> ```

I have tried with  unchecking top bar, bottom bar, `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` but none of them worked.

Can anyone explain why this is only happening in iOS 11?

Comment: Same problem with me as well

Comment: Are you using safe area on iOS 11?

Comment: Yes, I'm using safe area but it not worked. @MilanNosáľ

Comment: Try setting contentInset for `TabBar Controller`

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
```

to make your NavigationBar Translucent.